# Display function names from Library: how to make completions work in Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, autocomplete, ide

- I created a library called `LibraryName`;

> The problem is that when I do
> `myLibrary.whateverFunc().whateverSubFunc()`, I don't receive the
> completions, so I have to remember all function names by heart??

- All my functions are public, which means there are no `privFunc_`;
- All subFunctions are not showing;

Here follow my attempt:

```
function get(e){
  const myObject = LibraryName
    .factoryFunction()  // << when I type '.' no functions appear
}

/* ----------------------------------
 * Imaginary Line: Inside my library,  now ↓
 * ----------------------------------
*/
function factoryFunction(){
  this.access            = (id) => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  this.getSpreadSheet01  = (  ) => this.access ('*****');
  this.getSpreadsSheet02 = (  ) => this.access ('*****');
  return this
}
```

I was about to deploy it as a private add-on to check if it solves the problem, but it seems like a complicated process for me, so the question still remains: **why does the Subclasses of my library won't show?**

Comment: `const {getMySpreadsheets} = JourniqAutomation // << my library` if I don't do this and write straight inside onEdit >> const eClass = JourniqAutomation.getMySpreadsheets(), the same happens

Comment: `function onEdit(e) {  let range = e.range;  JourniqAutomation.foo(range) }` I found out that I can do this and work through `2022 Journiq` . It doesn't answer the question, anyway.

Comment: Are you able to access the functions and execute them?( without auto completion)

Comment: @TheMaster yes, I'm able. If I type them I can access their values normally, which makes me think it has nothing to do with permissions. Maybe it's the way i'm combining objects and functions, but honestly I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: You might try documenting the return object using [tag:jsdoc] in the library

Comment: @TheMaster the jsdoc library has actually worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624789/apps-script-subfunctions-of-my-library-not-showing#:%7E:text=You%20might%20try%20documenting%20the%20return%20object%20using%20jsdoc%20in%20the%20library) of @TheMaster  I could find out that JSDoc can solve generate the completions I need. I created a new Apps Script project, [connected it to the library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#:%7E:text=page.-,Add%20a%20library%20to%20your%20script%20project,-At%20the%20left), and organized the lines like this:

```
/**
 * Text sample, bla bla bla
 * @typedef {{propertyName1:type, propertyName2, propertyName3}} Foo
/*
/** 
 * Bla bla bla
 * @typedef {Array<Foo>} FooList
*/

/** Bla bla bla
 * @typedef {Object} LibraryName
 * @property {function():FooList} method1
 * 
 * Here you write what this function does. 
 * You can even give examples using tables, like this ↓
 * 
 * ## Sample table
 *
 * | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |
 * | :----:  | ------: | :------ |
 * | v1      | v2      | v3      |
 * | V4      | v5      | v6      |
*/

function myFunction() {
    /** @type {LibraryName} */
    let Library = YourLibrary;
    let array = Library.method1()
    console.log(array)
}
```

This is an actual example of how it's being shown in my browser. The way of formatting it is similar to Stackflow's.

[image]

Defining the type of array of objects can even give you further information. (another real example ↓)

[image]

Comment: You can add a sample jsdoc return object for the code in your question to improve this answer.